# Book series in which fairies can become human and return to being fairies if they die

Tags: story-identification, books, fairy

When I was in high school, I found this book series that I started reading. I'm pretty sure it's only 3 books long but high school was 5 years ago. It pops it my head every now and than and now I want to find it.

What I remember from it was this girl was a human and used to be a fairy or something magical. Her mom died but apparently if you die as a human you go back to be a fairy I believe. It was in the teen section I think.

Answer (score 1):

Possibly the [Faery Rebels](https://www.goodreads.com/series/45689-faery-rebels) trilogy by R J Anderson? The main character from the first book, Knife, is a human-who-used-to-be-a-fairy in the other two books; and fairies that die in the first book can leave eggs, which hatch out again as baby fairies.